# JS multiple replace

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a problem.

I don't know how to explain it, so I'll give an example:

I want to replace `=)` with `bla1`,
and I want to replace `=))` with `bla2`.

But what happens is that `=))` becomes `bla1)`

What can I do?

Thanks a lot,
and sorry for my English

**EDIT:**
I can't replace `=))` first.
 I have more signs like this. (>:),:((,:)) and more...). All of them are in array and I use a loop to replace all of them. It'll be very complicated to change all of them. the Array is big

Comment: Replace `=))` first :)

Answer (score 1):

First replace the more specialized one.

1. Replace =)) with bla2
2. Replace =) with bla1

**Example**

```
var text = "This =)) is =) some demo =)) =) =)) text";
text = text.replace(/=\)\)/g, "bla2"); // =))
text = text.replace(/=\)/g, "bla1"); // =)

// text = This bla2 is bla1 some demo bla2 bla1 bla2 text
```

**FAILED Example**

```
var text = "This =)) is =) some demo =)) =) =)) text :))";
text = text.replace(/=\)/g, "bla1"); // =)
text = text.replace(/=\)\)/g, "bla2"); // =))

// text = This bla1) is bla1 some demo bla1) bla1 bla1) text
```

Comment: I can't do that. there are a lot of that example, and it'll take a lot of time.

Comment: what do you mean it will take a lot of time? It is 2 replace statements one preceding the other. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I only gave an example. I have more signs like this. (`>:)`,`:((`,`:))` and more...). All of them are in array and I use a loop to replace all of them. It'll be very complicated to change all of them. the Array is big

Comment: Please see my updated example. You do not need to use a loop. If i misunderstand then please post some code. The problem you described getting "bla1)" seem to be you not replacing the most specialized one first.

Comment: Look at my full code: http://pastebin.com/cU8mNFvi
(Look at the second array, and the loop)

Comment: A lot of code. But exactly my point. In emotes you have this:
sad=:(                      
crying: :((
But if you replace :( with "sad" as an example. Then you cannot replace :(( later basue now the text will contain "sad(". Do you understand? ":((" has to be replaced first.

Comment: Yes, I understand why it happens, but there is no other way ? you saw the list...  a lot of work to do

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
For example...

```
If you want to replace multiple "-" from single string
var str = "only-for-test";
str.replace(/-/g, "");

//out put : onlyfortest
```